# Error using Scapy

Tags: scapy

I am using Python2.5 and Scapy2.2.0 . When I execute the following code:

```
from scapy.all import *

a = IP(dst='10.100.95.184')
a.src = "10.100.95.22"
ab = a/ICMP()
sendp(ab)
```

I get the following error:

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\att.py", line 6, in <module>
    sendp(ab)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 259, in sendp
    __gen_send(conf.L2socket(iface=iface, *args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count, verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 237, in __gen_send
    os.write(1,".")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Any idea how I can correct this?

Comment: Do you have administrative permission?

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem (not this exactly error message) and it looks like not a problem in your code. I fixed my scenario reinstalling the scapy package. Have you tried it? Try to upgrade your Python version to the next one too.

Good luck !